# [Graph api]returning limited set of records

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get emails from a certain folder within my mailbox . API called me/mailfolders(id)/messages . But it returns me only 10 records . how to I get all messages or if there is a huge set how to paginate it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried appending $top=200 it gave me results for top 200 emails . Is this the only way ?